# Enabling SSL in checkout page, Unable to proceed to next step after billing

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.5, magento-1.6

In magento, If I didnt enable the SSL, the site and checkout process works fine. If I enable the secure url, then when we enters to checkout page, after entering the billing information; If I click on continue, then it didnt proceed to next step. It stays on same page. I came to know that the cookie expires and shows 403 error when we click on continue in billing page. This is happens on enabling the secure Url. So how I can get rid of this?[image: tamper data]

Answer (score 0):

Is it a OnePageCheckout?
It seems that the browser refuse to make ajax calls to the server.
Could you please post the header of the https ajax request?

Comment: I have added image of header data to my question.Yes it is one page checkout only. When tampering data no data is saving by ajax call

Comment: You should debug in
    Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
In function
    protected function _expireAjax()

   if (!$this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->hasItems()
        || $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getHasError()
        || $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getIsMultiShipping()) {
    $this->_ajaxRedirectResponse();

The function _ajaxRedirectResponse send 403 code with Session Expired!

Comment: So do i need to add the above code to my onepagecontroller.php?